# How to add COUNTIFS, I looked at other topics but it didn't work

Tags: excel, google-docs

I am trying to set up a countif in one workbook but across multiple sheets.

I got this far: `countifs(Sheet1!A:A,"Banana",Sheet1!C:C,"Yellow")` : and it gave me the answer, but now I am trying to do the same thing across sheets and to sum the answer. In my head it would be something like this:

```
=SUM((countifs(Sheet1!A:A,"Banana",Sheet1!C:C,"Yellow"),(COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A:A, "Banana",SHeet1!C:C,"Yellow"))
```

but that's not working.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in Excel or in a Google Doc?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Does the formula produce an error code? Does the formula produce a number that is not what you were expecting? Please be specific.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting the sum from BOTH sheets: 
You capitalized the H in Sheet1 and forgot to change it to Sheet2

`=SUM(COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A:A,"Banana",Sheet1!C:C,"Yellow"),COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A:A,"Banana",Sheet2!C:C,"Yellow")`

---

Unless you want Banana from Sheet2 and Yellow from Sheet1 in which case:
`=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A:A,"Banana",Sheet1!C:C,"Yellow")`

Answer (score 0):

This works only in Excel:

Put a list of the sheet names in a range and name that range `Sheets` then use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("'" & Sheets & "'!A:A"),"Banana",INDIRECT("'" & Sheets & "'!C:C"),"Yellow"))
```